# Changing title text in hot questions shortlist

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

Can we take the title text out of the URLs in the Hot Questions shortlist?

Currently, if a visited question's title is  edited, the URL changes too, so the link is rendered as if it had not been visited.

Comment: Good point, never noticed this!